# Is it possible to send realtime data from arduino to a server api?

Tags: spring-rest, arduino-esp8266

I know how to build server api with java. Is it possible to send real time data from the arduino to my server api to save real time data.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If its possible to save the data sent in an HTTP request from the arduino to a Java web server? If so, yes, look into different DB options such as SQL or Redis.

Comment: i see people recommend use MQTT instead of HTTP. So i thought i can only use mqtt request for real time data. So when should we use MQTT request?

Comment: open a socket and send the data. TCP socket on Arduino is EthernetClient or WiFiClient

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's certainly possible however your server API must also be taken into consideration for best practices.

Typically you would use a protocol called MQTT to achieve this. It enables you to transmit data from resource constrained devices to a server, however HTTP has also been used. It really depends on the kinds of performance & reliability needs of your system.

If you're using a popular cloud platform they offer managed IOT services that provide well defined API's to do this.